# how to send data to it when launch a background app?

Tags: android, android-intent, background

my app need to launch a app and send my data to it.
i used this to launch the app(both new and from background):

```
Intent wakeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

wakeIntent.putExtra("type", type);

wakeIntent.putExtra("scheduleId", id);
wakeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

//welcome is launcher of the target app                                                 

wakeIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), WelcomeActivity.class);
wakeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(wakeIntent);
```

the WelcomeActivity can receive the data "type","id" in intent when i launch the app as new ,
but if the app has already launched and switched background, it occurs that the wakened background app can not receive the data. how to

best regards to any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `Shared Preferences` by storing  `"type","id"` in Shared Preferences before launching `WelcomeActivity` from your Current Activity as:

For example i'm starting `WelcomeActivity` on button click from `FirstActivity` :

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
SharedPreferences myPrefs;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       void onClick() {
         //Create 

        myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
        prefsEditor.putString("type", type);
        prefsEditor.putString("scheduleId", scheduleId);
        prefsEditor.commit();

       //start WelcomeActivity here
    Intent wakeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    wakeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    //welcome is launcher of the target app                                                 

    wakeIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), WelcomeActivity.class);
    wakeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(wakeIntent);

        }
    });
    }
}
```

And in `WelcomeActivity` Activity read this `SharedPreferences` in both  `onCreate` and `onResume` as:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
SharedPreferences myPrefs;

public static boolean status=false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        // this will read when first time start
        myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        String strtype = myPrefs.getString("type", "nothing");
        String strscheduleId = myPrefs.getString("scheduleId", "0");
        status=true;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // The activity has become visible (it is now "resumed").
       if(status!=true){
                 // this will read when first time start
        myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        String strtype = myPrefs.getString("type", "nothing");
        String strscheduleId = myPrefs.getString("scheduleId", "0");
       }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
     // Another activity is taking focus (this activity is about to be "paused").

        // reset counter here
        status=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: how it work if WelcomeActivity and FirstActivity are in different apps?

Comment: @YunfeiTang : you have not this impotent point in your question. any way if both application is your on then you can read / write SharedPreferences from any application without any issue

Comment: if you have any issue still in reading or writing values in SharedPreferences in different application's then tell me i will try to help u